# modify HTTP header in web service call

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, cxf, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have a web service where the customer sends the http header with the SOAP action with single quotes (...;*action='myServiceOp'*).
We used **traditional** **Websphere** application server 8, but migrated to Websphere **Liberty**. Now Liberty does not like this single quotes and responds with

```
The given SOAPAction 'myServiceOp' does not match an operation.
```

So I thought I use a handler to modify this parameter and did the following in the handleMessage method:

```
Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) ctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
if(requestHeaders.get("Content-Type") != null) {
    List<String> cleanedContentType =  requestHeaders.get("Content-Type");
    String cleanedString = requestHeaders.get("Content-Type").get(0).replace("'", "");
    cleanedContentType.clear();
    cleanedContentType.add(cleanedString);
    requestHeaders.put("Content-Type", cleanedContentType);         
}
```

In my logs I can see that the request headers were set accordingly, but my web service still answers with the above error.

Liberty uses **CXF** and we had already a lot of issues with that, so I suspect that this is somehow interfering.

Is there maybe a Liberty configuration in the server.xml?

If an interceptor is needed (or something CXF specific), do I need an extra feature? Because I get *ClassNotFound* errors when I tried that the last time.

Kind regards

Comment: You need to modify the `SOAPAction` HTTP header , not the `Content-Type`  header. The Content-Type header should just state `Content-Type: text/xml charset="utf-8"`  for a SOAP request, that's not the one you need to modify.

Comment: As far as I know the SOAPaction header is deprecated